# arccos and arcsin integral contradiction:

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I am shown:

$$f(x) = \arcsin x \implies f'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$f(x) = \arccos x \implies f'(x) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

These two derivatives can be very readily derived by a bit of implicit differentiation. However... I want to undo my differentiation for both expressions.

I set up the integrals and now note that the only difference between the two derivatives is a negative sign. Suppose that for the arccos(x) derivative, I factor out the negative sign before integrating the expression, as $-1$ is a constant and the constnat factor rule states that:

$$\int k \frac{dy}{dx} dx = k \int \frac{dy}{dx} dx$$

However, due to this, I end up with the false equality:

$$-\arccos(x)=\arcsin(x)$$

Which doesn't hold for any $x$ at all!

What have I done wrong, why cant one simply factor out the negative sign for the arccos derivative expression?

Comment: You forgot constant of integration $k=\pi/2$

Comment: True, thanks! An added $pi/2$ on the LHS  makes the expressions equal. So my mistake was in not considering that though the derivative of 2 functions may be very close, the original functions from which they were derived may have different constants of integration!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two functions defined over an interval that have the same derivative  differ by a constant.

Since the derivatives of $\arcsin x$ and $-\arccos x$ are both equal to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ on the interval $(-1,1)$, you can say that there exists $c$ such that
$$
\arcsin x=c-\arccos x
$$
If you evaluate at $0$, you get
$$
0=\arcsin 0=c-\arccos 0=c-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Therefore, for all $x\in(-1,1)$,
$$
\arcsin x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos x
$$
and this holds by continuity also for $x=-1$ and $x=1$.

---

You get a similar “contradiction” if you do
$$
\log x=\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\int\frac{2}{2x}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{2x}\,d(2x)=\log(2x)
$$
without taking into account the “constant of integration”; indeed
$$
\log x = \log(2x)-\log 2
$$